# Devise + omniauth-facebook Add permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

we are letting the users sign up with minimum permissions like this:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
              :scope => 'email,offline_access,user_about_me'
end
```

We do this to increase signup rate (the less permissions you ask for the higher the conversion).

But later when for example the user wants to fb share something we need the publish_stream permission.

Does anyone know how to elevate the fb permissions? to for example: 'email,offline_access,user_about_me,publish_stream'

I'm aware that the user has to go through the oauth dialog again..but how to do this?

thanks

Comment: have you figured this out yet? asking myself the same question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to add `setup: true` to be able to upgrade the list of permissions of the service:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
                  :scope => 'email,offline_access,user_about_me',
                  :setup => true
end
```

Add two routes in `routes.rb`:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/auth/:provider/upgrade' => 'omniauth_callbacks#upgrade', as: :user_omniauth_upgrade
  get '/users/auth/:provider/setup', :to => 'omniauth_callbacks#setup'
end
```

The first route is where the user should be linked to by using `user_omniauth_upgrade_path(:facebook)`. The second setup route is the callback which omniauth will call internally and we can use to change the scope parameter.

These go into `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`:

```
def upgrade
  scope = nil

  if params[:provider] == "facebook"
    scope = 'email,offline_access,user_about_me,publish_stream'
  end

  redirect_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(params[:provider]), flash: {scope: scope}
end
```

When you specify `setup: true` inside of the omniauth configuration `setup_path` is called by default. We will use this to change the scope from the default in the strategy. Add this to `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`:

```
def setup
  request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options['scope'] = flash[:scope] || request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options['scope']
  render :text => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
end
```

Finally, in your views you can add:

```
<%= link_to "Upgrade Access", user_omniauth_upgrade_path(:facebook) %>
```

> Source:
>   http://willschenk.com/setting-up-devise-with-twitter-and-facebook-and-other-omniauth-schemes-without-email-addresses/#passing-dynamic-scopes-to-omniauth

Comment: It appears that you get a double render now if you use `render :text` in #setup. It works with `head :no_content`

Answer (score -3):

use only two permission for login with facebook -  1)email 2) publish_stream

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],{:scope => 'email, publish_stream', :client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_file => "#{Rails.root}/config/ca-bundle.crt" } } }
```

Comment: Not sure what u mean by that. What i want to do is add new permissions later on. 

Lets say at some point the user wants to do something that requires the upload_photo permission. how can I open a popup with facebook connect that specifically asks for that right?